# Angularjs remove custom directive and child directives from DOM

Tags: angularjs, dom

I have a single page angularjs app. I use $routeProvider to load up custom directives shown in the code below.

Now each custom directive loaded is made up of additional sub custom directives. All the custom directives have isolated scopes.

What I need is when the view changes is the scope to be destroyed as well as remove the directives from the DOM under the current view. I've got as far as the following code. Can this be achieved with Jquery lite and/or angularjs only? If so how do I remove the parent and child directives from the DOM for a particular view? Thanks in advance.

**Custom Directive Form**

```
 angular.module("form", [])
    .directive("form",['$http','$rootScope','$location', function($http,$rootScope,$location){

return{
            link: function(scope,element,attrs){ 
               //functions go heere

                //destroy scope and remove from DOM on route change
                $rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeSuccess", function(event, next, current) {
                  if($location.path()!=='/form'){
                        scope.$destroy();
                        console.log('This should not be displayed on route change');
                    }   
                });



                //function and scopes go here
            },//return
            restrict:"A", 
            replace:true,
            templateUrl:"partials/form/form.html",//template
            transclude:true, //incorporate additional data within
            scope:{}
        }//return
```

}])

**ng-view/routeProvider**

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
        //configure the routes
        $routeProvider

        .when('/',{
        // route for the home page
            templateUrl:'partials/login/login.html',
            controller:'loginCtrl'      
        })

        .when('/home',{
        // route for the home page

            templateUrl:'partials/home/home.html',
            template:'<div home></div>'         
        })

        .when('/company',{
        // route for the sites& companies
            template:'<div company></div>'      
        })

        .when('/form',{
        // route for form
            template:'<div form></div>' 
        })

        .otherwise({
            //when all else fails
            templateUrl:'partials/login/login.html',
            controller:'loginCtrl'
        });

}]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Please see this reference:
 [How to manually take an Angular directive out of the DOM](http://www.mattzeunert.com/2014/11/03/manually-removing-angular-directives.html)

As per the source reference :

Steps:
1. Delete the directive's scope
2. Delete the directive's DOM

```
childScope.$destroy();  //IF THE DIRECTIVE WAS CREATED DYNAMICALLY OR ELSE WE MAY USE angular.element(DIRECTIVES-DOM).scope().$destroy()
$('.my-directive-placeholder').empty(); //DELETE DIRECTIVE'S DOM
```